# Error CentOS 6.8 - Odoo 10 - Version xlwt

Tags: odoo, centos6, python-2.6, xlwt, odoo-10

I have a problem with the installation of python-xlwt in Odoo 10. I have installed Odoo10 in CentOS. I have installed it with pip install xlwt, but it’s installed the version 1.0.0 and, in the archive requirements of Odoo 10, put to need the version 1.1.2. How can I resolve this problem?

Here is my configuration:

> ```
> Name : python-xlwt 
> Arch : x86_64 
> Version : 1.0.0 
> Release : 1.el6 
> Size : 180 k 
> Repo : forensics 
> Summary : python-xlwk - a library to generate spreadsheet files compatible with 
>         : Microsoft Excel versions 95 to 2003 
> URL : http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt 
> License : GPL 
> Description : python-xlwk is a library for generating spreadsheet files that are 
>             : compatible with Excel 97/2000/XP/2003, OpenOffice.org Calc, and 
>             : Gnumeric. xlwt has full support for Unicode. Excel spreadsheets can be 
>             : generated on any platform without needing Excel or a COM server. The 
>             : only requirement is Python 2.3 to 2.6. xlwt is a fork of pyExcelerator.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can install specific version of any python library using pip as like below.

If you want to install xlwt version 1.1.2 then you need to execute command as like below.

sudo pip install xlwt==1.1.2

It will install xlwt with version 1.1.2 and if already installed with old version then system will upgrade it and if already installed with newest version then system will downgrade it.